# Error en línea 2, variables 'casilla'. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'casillas' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, variables-globales

Tengo este problema, este código hace parte de uno más grande, es sobre el juego ta-te-ti/tic-tac-toe/triqui
Llevo 4 noches intentando arreglarlo. Yo quería arreglar que en los turnos no me salían los nombres, pero no toqué para nada esa línea, pues no es necesario, y el programa corría bien, pero ahora se paró en esa línea.
Edit: Ya usé Global y se arregló, pero aún los nombres de los jugadores no aparecen cuando es el turno de cada quien y tampoco salen cuando se felicita al ganador aunque en el print los incluyo, pero sí salen los nombres en la bienvenida que es el inicio del juego. Ayuda, por favor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Métele un self.casillas en la definición y cuando lo uses. No lo está encontrando. Y sino pásalo por parámetro.

Comment: No utilices imágenes para compartir código... Por favor hecha un vistazo [a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ¿Cual `self`? No hay ninguna clase aqui.